# incompatible embedded font @font-face flex

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex4, flex4.5

```
warning: incompatible embedded font 'TwoFontsITried' specified for spark.components::Label This component requires that the embedded font be declared with embedAsCFF=true
```

I am using `Flex 4.6 with Apache Flex 4.9.1 Library`.

Code is given below:

```
/* CSS file */
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

@font-face {
    src:url("../fonts/DS-DIGII.TTF");
    fontFamily: "DS-DIGII";
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
    embedAsCFF:true;
}

s|Label {
    font-size: 12;
    font-family: "DS-DIGII";
    /*text-decoration:line-through;*/
    color:#000000;
}
```

I have tried all different solutions i found on SO and other similar communities. Font is not gonna show up.

From this link i found that

```
Apache Flex 4.9.1 need optional dependencies for Embedded Font Support. tried to use dependencies for `Apache Flex 4.9.1 using Apache ANT 1.9.1` with this command

cd <flex.dir>/frameworks
ant thirdparty-downloads
```

I think issue is because of this new sdk needs dependencies but changing sdk and compiler from `apache flex 4.9.1` to `flex 4.6` is generating this issue

```
Invalid application descriptor: Unknown namespace: _http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.4
```

Any simple solution to embed font in above situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah, problem is solved.. font embedded and guess was right, libraries were missing to embed font in my application.

I deleted Apache Flex 4.9.1 sdk and re-installed with the installer from here http://flex.apache.org/installer.html with Optional Embedded Font option selected along with compulsory SDK options